# PHP Class - getting property of non-object & undefined Notices

Tags: php, wordpress

****edit have fixed this code - see inline comments marked EDIT ****

I'm getting a few PHP debug notices when using the following code in a wordpress theme. It's my first attempt at using a PHP class, and it does work ok, but the debug notices concern me. I am calling the method in my PHP template thus:

`<?php $getjobmeta->job_type(); ?>` & `<?php $getjobmeta->post_types(); ?>`

The debug notices are as follows:

`Notice: Undefined variable: post`

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

From the research I have done this looks like an issue with the class sometimes returning a non object, so i tried wrapping the 'echo' in `isset` and `is_object` but I just can't fix those notices.

Here is the simplified code. For the sake of my sanity I could really use some help.

```
    // define the class

class getJobMeta { 

    var $jobmeta_echo; // set a class variable to store our echo

    public function job_type() { // define a class function and make it public

            global $post // EDIT IN FIX

          if ( 'post' == get_post_type() )  {       
                   $jobtype = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'job-type', '<span itemprop="employmentType">', ', ', '</span>', 0 ); // 0 at end of arg signifies that we don't want links outputted
                   }

          else { 
                    return ''; 
               }

     echo $jobtype.$this->jobmeta_echo;

     } // end function job_type

    // define post type


  public function post_types() { 

               global $post // EDIT IN FIX


        if ('post' == get_post_type())  {
                    $posttype = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'channel', '<strong class="channel-links clearfix">', ', ', '</strong>', 1); // 1 means output as link

            } elseif ( 'blog' == get_post_type() )  {
                $posttype = '<a href="/blog/" class="post-type-label">Blog</a>';

            } elseif ( 'type2' == get_post_type() )  {
                $posttype = '<a href="/type2/" class="post-type-label">Type2</a>';

        } else {
                $posttype = '';
        }


    echo $posttype.$this->jobmeta_echo;  // EDIT TYPO


    } // end function posttype


   } // end getJobMeta class

    // set the class into a variable
    $getjobmeta = new getJobMeta;
```

Thanks
Ben

Comment: You are using `$post->ID`  in 2 places, which appear to be out of scope in your class. Perhaps these should be `$this->post->ID`?  I don't know the internals of Wordpress. `$posttype = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, `

Comment: "calling the class" is incorrect. You can call method. To call a method you should create an object or call static method. Can you provide more code? How $getjobmeta was defined?

Comment: @Michael, yep you spotted it. It was a wordpress issue. I needed to define global $post in my function as hakre kindly pointed out. Thanks!

Comment: @Vitalmax - sorry you have lost me. Are you saying I should construct my class differently? Any guidance on best practice would be awesome. This is my first stab don't forget.  Thanks for the input tho.

Comment: @Vitalmax - ah I see what you mean. I have edited the question and changed "calling the class" to "calling the method". Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking about Wordpress here and `$post` is a global variable so you need to define it within your functions:

```
public function job_type() {
    global $post;
    ...

public function post_types() { 
    global $post;
    ...
```

Comment: hakre, spot on. Thanks.global $post and yes sorry this is clearly a wordpress related issue.

Comment: Actually I am now getting a new Notice: `Undefined property: getJobMeta::$our_echo` on the calls that output HTML strings such as post type blog. Could this be to do with unescaped HTML?

Comment: No that has nothing to do with unescaped HTML. That has something to do with the variable and that it is not a member of `getJobMeta`. See the variable definition on top of your class. It's called `jobmeta_echo` not `our_echo`. PHP warns you that you accessed a member which does not exist (e.g. misspelled variable name).

Comment: Great catch. Thank you so much! I should have spotted to be fair. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The warnings are most likely from this line:

```
$jobtype = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'job-type', '<span itemprop="employmentType">', ', ', '</span>', 0 ); // 0 at end of arg signifies that we don't want
```

Specifically `$post->ID`

This is not initialised in your code, hence the two warnings.